# 500 internal server error on gitlab

Tags: gitlab

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@gitlab.dev.sample.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.42 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.9 Server at gitlab.dev.sample.com Port 80

Comment: help me to solve this error

Comment: For bugs, open an issue at: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq , and give precise indications of how to reproduce. What page have you visited? Does it always happens, or only in certain cases? Which cases? What is the gitlab version?

Comment: Thanks for giving a reply,My gitlab version is "Git-1.9.4-preview20140611" The file commiting perfectly but in the url its showing 500 internal server error.